# About the idiom? ”Walking underwater"

Tags: word-usage

This could be a low quality question, but when I was watching the ten-year-old famous T.V show "Prison Break," I encountered this idiom, but neither my dictionary nor googling was of any help.

Does this mean "I/You/He/She/They am/are/is/are so stressed"? I guess?

Comment: I'm not aware of "walking underwater" as an idiom. Do you have more context? It might have just been a metaphor created by the writer, rather than a common phrase.

Comment: are you talking about this [quote](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0928317/quotes?item=qt0220276)? If yes, then it is not an idiom. When you walk underwater or swim, it is very quite and calm down there.

Comment: CORRECTION: If yes, then it is not an idiom. When you walk underwater or swim, it is very quiet and peaceful (until you encounter a shark!) down there. This peace and quietness at the prison is very similar to that when you are walking/swimming underwater.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. And...ahm...since I am still watching, a FBI guy ( who is working for a "government" thing which set an innocent man to the prison to death ) is taking pills every moment and a female doctor says "You got to know it's not real hard for me to recognize a junkier" and and conversation went on and finally the FBI guy adimits he is an addict and he gave "her" a pill called "Veratrill" ( which I don't know about )  and she said to him "Benzodiaepines's a hardcore tranquilizer, man". He adimits her answer and

Comment: said "20milligrams" and the woma says the line in the question...thank you anyway for your comment.

Comment: @KentaroTomono Please do read my comment again. I have provided a link for your quote.

Comment: Her real comment is "You must feel like you are walking underwater". So, if Mr.Graham's answer is correct, is the woman insinuating the F.B.I guy would feel very relaxed every moment he takes the pill????????

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I read the link and I understood it. Thank you so much for having helped me about this.

Comment: I apologize. I should've thanked Mr Userner for providing me with the link. I am sorry.

Comment: @KentaroTomono It's okay. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Like walking underwater" isn't common enough to be an idiom but it's a great example of a [simile](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/miscellaneous/metaphors-similes-and-idioms/).  Both idioms and similes are types of figurative language.  An idiom is a fixed expression that is widely known and used to mean something contrary to the literal meaning.  A simile makes a comparison or analogy between unrelated things.

In this case, being under the influence of the "hardcore tranquilizer" makes movement feel slower and require slightly more effort than usual, just as "walking underwater" would do.
It also might be quiet and peaceful under the right circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, I finished watching this series and if you have watched, wouldn't you think this series is getting more and more weierd as the seasons go on.... it is getting like a genocide or mass killing, haha, I am sorry I went off the line.